# Second conditional with neither...nor

Tags: conditional-constructions

Are these two sentences correct? Are they the same?

1. I swear if my mother didn't do that, neither you nor your friend could bring me to this place.
2. I swear neither you nor your friend could bring me to this place, if my mother didn't do that.

Does each sentence above mean the following?
'I swear if my mother didn't bring me to this place neither you nor your friend could.'

I want to form a sentence like sentence number 1 and 2 above to mean this: (I swear if my mother didn't bring me to this place neither you nor your friend 
could.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manzimes: 1 and 2 look equivalent to me, but both are inferior to the sentence that follows "following?" except it needs some editing:

'I swear, if my mother couldn't bring me to this place, neither you nor your friend could either.'

or, if you want to keep it weird:

'I swear, if my mother didn't bring me here, neither you nor your friend did either.'